# Retrieve JPG pictures from URL (Python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib3

I'm trying to retrieve JPG images from http ULRs (to display them in a GUI) with the following Python code:

```
import urllib3
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

conn = urllib3.connection_from_url('http://www.solarspace.co.uk/')
img_file = conn.urlopen('GET', 'http://www.solarspace.co.uk/PlanetPics/Neptune/NeptuneAlt1.jpg')
image = StringIO(img_file.read())
image.seek(0)
resized_image = Image.open(image)
```

However, this gives me this error message: "IOError: cannot identify image file".

The reason why I'm using urllib3 is because I need a persistent connection (to send multiple requests), which is not available with urllib/urllib2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work if you use `img_file.data` instead of `img_file.read()`. `img_file.read()` is meant to be used when you specify `preload_content=False` on the request. Now that I think about it, it's not very intuitive, perhaps `img_file.read()` should be aware of the cached preloaded content, or perhaps it should raise an exception if it has already been consumed. The plan was to make `preload_content=False` default but turns out there are a lot of edge cases which fall under normal usage that are hard to satisfy. I opened a bug to fix this in the future: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/102

Anyways, using `img_file.data` should fix your problem. Sorry for the confusion! :)

Also I suggest using `conn.request(...)` instead of the lower-level `conn.urlopen(...)`, and perhaps use `PoolManager` if you might be going cross-domain (no reason not to use it, really). Try this:

```
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', 'http://www.solarspace.co.uk/PlanetPics/Neptune/NeptuneAlt1.jpg')
>>> resized_image = Image.open(StringIO(r.data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Everything's fine now.

Answer (score 2):

As always, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) to the rescue:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.solarspace.co.uk/PlanetPics/Neptune/NeptuneAlt1.jpg')
>>> i = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
>>> i.size
(262, 299)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `r.content` - for some reason I was trying to do this with `r.text` which doesn't work so well since it makes it unicode

Answer (score 0):

When save it, you can do:

```
with open('##.jpg','wb') as fout:
     fout.write(r.content)
```